# Evaluate $T$* at the given vector in $ P_1(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

For problem 3(c)
[image]

I get that $T(at + b) = (at +b)' + 3(at + b) = a + 3at + 3b$. Then I get that

$\langle a + 3at + 3b, 4 - 2t \rangle$.

By definition, $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} -6at^2 + (10a -6b)t + 4a +12b \,dt$,

but the answer I find online gives me

$\int_{-1}^{1} -6at^2 + (-2a + 6b)t + 4a +12b \,dt$.

I was wondering where I went wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you didn’t. It sure looks like the online answer is missing a term.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure if I was missing something important.